# How could I replace multiple div without set few functions onclick?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using vanilla JS for some reasons and trying to replace div content while click on li.

I'm tried to replace by function(target, source) but target is always = id.
So I'm clone my function and onclick li insert 2 functions + params.

```html
<body>
  <li onClick="replaceContentInContainer('target', 'replace_target_div2'); replaceContentInContainerTwo('targetTwo', 'replace_target_div2_02')">View Div 2</li>
  <li onClick="replaceContentInContainer('target', 'replace_target_div3'); replaceContentInContainerTwo('targetTwo', 'replace_target_div3_02')">View Div 3</li>
  <div>
    <span id="target">div1</span>
  </div>

  <div style="display:none">
    <span id="replace_target_div2">div2</span>
  </div>

  <div style="display:none">
    <span id="replace_target_div3">div3</span>
  </div>


  <div>
    <span id="targetTwo">div1</span>
  </div>

  <div style="display:none">
    <span id="replace_target_div2_02">div2 02</span>
  </div>

  <div style="display:none">
    <span id="replace_target_div3_02">div3 03</span>
  </div>

</body>
<script>
  function replaceContentInContainer(target, source) {
    document.getElementById(target).innerHTML = document.getElementById(source).innerHTML;
  }

  function replaceContentInContainerTwo(targetTwo, sourceTwo) {
    document.getElementById(targetTwo).innerHTML = document.getElementById(sourceTwo).innerHTML;
  }
</script>
```

I would like to have elegant way to do so.

Comment: Do you mean when page is load?

Comment: Can you please be a bit more clear on the expected result, please?

Comment: No as I mentioned while click on list item.
I'll change my code snippet for be a bit more clear.

Comment: Here is my sample for fruits and veggs - https://codepen.io/aviran/pen/VopVox.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you mean is that you want to keep your HTML clean.

You could use a click eventhandler on all li within a certain ul.

## HTML

```
<ul id="theList">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

## JS add Click event handler

```
// Get all list items in ul with id 'theList'
var listItems = document.querySelectorAll('#theList li');

// Add a click event handler on each list item
for (i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
 listItems[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
   console.log(this) // This is your target html
 });
}
```

For the last step I'm not sure what you want. I don't know how your source is chosen. I will edit if you explain it more.

Answer (score 0):

You can user this code:

```html
<body>
  <li onClick="replaceContentInContainer('target', 'div2');">View Div 2</li>
  <li onClick="replaceContentInContainer('target', 'div3')">View Div 3</li>
  <div>
    <span class="target">div1</span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <span class="target">div1</span>
  </div>

</body>
<script>
  function replaceContentInContainer(div, text) {
    var ids = document.getElementsByClassName(div);
    for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        ids[i].innerText = text;
    }
  }
  </script>
```

Comment: Thanks but I need to change multiple div elements and different content each. 
Example: Click on 'li-01' has to display 3 divs and different content each, while click on 'li-02' it should display 3 divs with different content each and than 'li-01' divs' content.

Comment: You need to pass the changed values from somewhere it might be an array of values or random or dynamic. So if it would we need to set somewhere to change different values for all.
Thanks for your responce :)